# Maya Python Script : Return True or False if an attribute is keyframed at that specific frame

Tags: python, maya, keyframe

I'm trying to complete my script and I had some issues.
Here is my script:

```
from maya import cmds
def correct_value(selection=None, prefix='', suffix=''):

    newSel = []
    if selection is None: 
        selection = cmds.ls ('*_control') 

    if selection and not isinstance(selection, list):
        newSel = [selection]

    for each_obj in selection:
        if each_obj.startswith(prefix) and each_obj.endswith(suffix) :
        newSel.append(each_obj)
        return newSel

def save_pose(selection):

     pose_dictionary = {}

     for each_obj in selection:
          pose_dictionary[each_obj] = {}
     for each_attribute in cmds.listAttr (each_obj, k=True):
          pose_dictionary[each_obj][each_attribute] = cmds.getAttr (each_obj + "." + each_attribute)

  return pose_dictionary


controller = correct_value(None,'left' ,'control' )


save_pose(controller)


def save_animation(selection, **keywords ):
     if "framesWithKeys" not in keywords:
         keywords["framesWithKeys"] = [0,1,2,3]

     animation_dictionary = {}
     for each_frame in keywords["framesWithKeys"]:
          cmds.currentTime(each_frame)
          animation_dictionary[each_frame] = save_pose(selection)

     return animation_dictionary

frames = save_animation (save_pose(controller) ) 
print frames
```

Now when I'm querying an attribute, I want to store a `True` or `False` value in the dictionary that says if that attribute has a keyframe at that frame you are checking, but only if it has a key on that frame.

For example,  let us say I have keys on my control's tx attribute at frames 1 and 5 and I want to have a dictionary key that I can check later to see if there were keys at those frames: when there is a key at that frame, return `true`; when there isn't, return `false`.
If `True`, I also want to save the tangent types of the keys.

Answer (score 2):

cmds.keyframes will give you all of the keyframe times for a given anim curve. So it's easy to find all the keys in the scene:

```
keytimes = {}
for item in cmds.ls(type = 'animCurve'):
    keytimes[item] =   cmds.keyframe(item,  query=True, t=(-10000,100000)) # this will give you the key times   # using a big frame range here to make sure we get them all

# in practice you'd probably pass 'keytimes' as a class member...
def has_key(item, frame, **keytimes):
    return frame in keytimes[item]
```

Or you can just check one at a time:

```
def has_key_at(animcurve, frame):
   return frame in  cmds.keyframe(animcurve,  query=True, t=(-10000,100000))
```

The likely problem you'll run into is unsnapped keys : if you have a key at frame 30.001 and you ask 'is there a key at 30' the answer will be no.  You could force integer keys like this:

```
for item in cmds.ls(type = 'animCurve'):
    keytimes[item] =   map (int, cmds.keyframe(item,  query=True, t=(-10000,100000)))

def has_key (item, frame, **keytimes):
    return int(frame) in keytimes[item]
```